# My A* search is actually filling as many possible nodes as it can! can you see where I have gone wrong?

Tags: java, processing, path-finding

I've been obsessing for a while now but I cant seem to find where in my code 
the A* algorithm isn't doing what its supposed to, the character doesn't like moving in a certain way
on the screen! I believe that the problem could be found by someone simply understanding the algorithm and
looking at the behaviour of the character and finding where the code could have gone wrong using mental deduction,

please find the whole thing here if you are interested 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByqChOExSzOYSnh4d3ptcVMxd3c&authuser=0

I hope that walking through the code and explaining whats going on I can help someone else find the flaw, I may
even stumble across it myself explaining it in this way.

But first, download it and run it, in the options menu select demo and hit 'p' before clicking on the screen, a 
series of vertices should show you the path selected, watch the character obviously not take the most optimised route.

also if you make a good level please send me the save game text file, would really appreciate that, jsut hit  t or e
to bring up build menu, to set no go parameters and one to bring up save menu in editor mode but 
PLEASE AVOID HITTING r OR n!! r resets to main while n will wipe

okay to start explaining the working parts of my code that are off;
this function is called when the mouse is clicked, the comments should explain but I will round up what its doing underneath

```
 //initialises the variables necessary to move the player to a clicked point on the screen, its called in `mouseClick()`
 //it takes the argument of a grid object, this is an instance of the whole maze class, the maze class contains an array of elements
 //called tiles, this are the nodes that you would find in a search algorithm, in the class itself you would find variables
 //that contain the tiles location (tilex and tiley) you will have to add the delta_x and delta_y to those location integers
 //you will find the heuristic value in the tile, its changed each time the mouse is clicked, you will also find `xgrid` and `ygrid`
 //this symbolises where you would find the tile in the maze grid itself, these values should be self explanatory once you were
 //a little familiar with the A* algorithm, I find this link contains a good explanation
  void mouse_move(Grid g_ob) {

    //sets Boolean found to false as calling this function means that the pathis no longer found
    found = false;

    //resets error flag
    error = false;

    //set moving to false again to stop the player if it is
    moving = false;

    clear_arrays();

    //a grid object is instantiated with a copy of the grid object on click, this is so that player can work with an instance of the grid
    //in order to search for the paths through the maze itself, I will have to do something about doors being closed once the path  has already 
    // been set for the player to move to, else the player will woner through a closed door.
    grid_object = g_ob;

    //sets Pvector to store mouses last clicked position
    dest.x = mouseX;
    dest.y = mouseY;

    //sets the destination tile to a copy of the one clicked on
    grid_object.dest_tile = grid_object.pos_at_grid( (int)dest.x, (int)dest.y);    

    //initialise the temp_tile object with the tile that the player is presently occupying, add that to both the closed list
    //and the list open list, parent is to keep track of order of travel for later retracing route to start
    grid_object.temp_tile = grid_object.pos_at_grid( width/2, height/2);  
    closed_list.add( grid_object.temp_tile);

    //sets the id of the start position to be found, this is for construct paths arguments
    //it will know when to stop tracing steps back
    int start_id =  closed_list.get(closed_list.size()-1).id;
    //loop owns logic that initialises an array that moves tile by tile
    //if it loops too many times or gets to the destination tile it stops
    while (!found) {

      //add to open adds tiles to the open list, the logic in this function contains a large part of the
      //logic required in the A* path finding method.
      add_to_open(closed_list.get(closed_list.size()-1).xgrid, closed_list.get(closed_list.size()-1).ygrid);

      //initialise the temp tile with the lowest score from the open list after removing it from the closed list
      //this is one complete cycle of the A* path finding method 
      grid_object.temp_tile = return_lowest();

      //this adds that found node to the closed_list, this is part of the A* algorithm which needs a list
      //to check for nodes that have been selected from
      closed_list.add( grid_object.temp_tile);

      //if total score is really high something has gone wrong
      if (closed_list.get(closed_list.size()-1).total_score > 10000) {

        //set error to true
        error = true;
        break;
      }
    }

  //so long as everything went well a path was found else there was an error and paths must be cleared
    if (!error) {

      //reads the closed_list and constructs a path by going backwards through parent objects
      //until the parent object with the same id as the starting object is found, this is so path can
      //be walked through by the go here function 
      construct_path(start_id);

      //moving is set to true,
      moving = true;
    } else {

      println("path not found, total path became too large:= "+closed_list.get(closed_list.size()-1).total_score);

      //clears arrays close open and path for re - use
      clear_arrays();
    }
  }
```

So basically this function resets destination variables , found destination and moving flags, it uses a function that takes
a pixel location and returns a tile which it then adds onto the beginning of the closed list, this tile should be thought
of as the starting node.

Next this function enters a loop that will loop up until the found flag is set to true, while it loops the function adds
the last element of the closed list to the add_to_open function, this function takes x and y arguments that relate to a 
tile in this case, the last tile added to the closed list, and evaluates them, I will show the add to open function below
and explain it, first:

- what has happened so far pertains to the first thing one has to do in the A* search algorithm, you have to add the starting position-
- to the closed list and add its surrounding nodes to the open list, the nodes are only added to the open list under certain conditions-

-this is what the next function will do;

```
  //this function gets each surrounding tile from the tile at args x and y grid positions and checks if they are 
  //of a too higher node value to be considered or on the closed list already, if they are it doesn't add them
  //if they are not it calls an evaluation function to see if they should be added to the open_list or not
  void add_to_open(int x, int y) {
//loops through kernel array, the idea is to add the kernel values to a central x and y coordinate
//in order to return the surrounding tiles                  
for (int sx = 0; sx < 3; sx++) {
  for (int sy = 0; sy < 3; sy++) {

    //adds nearby tile to tile at args using the tile_at_pos function, similar to the pos at grid function
    //but it returns the tile at the x and y positions of a grid in the lucidian sense
    Grid.Tile temp = grid_object.tile_at_pos(x+kernel[sx], y+kernel[sy]);

    //if the tile around tile at args is not the tile at args and so long as the surrounding tile
    //has a cost less than 10000
    if ( temp.cost < 9999) {

      //the A* algorithm requires that a movement cost be applied to each tile 10 for adjacent tiles and 14 for
      //diagonal ones, this heuristic must only be applied in context to the tile as its checked as a surrounding tile
      //the following loop ads a 10 if the kernel contains a 0 and 14 if there is no zero as diagonal tiles will be a combination
      //of one and minus one.
      if (kernel[sx]+x == 0 || kernel[sy]+y == 0) {

        temp.movement_cost = 10;
      } else {

        temp.movement_cost = 14;
      }

     //adds the terrain score of the tile also part of the movement cost
      temp.movement_cost += temp.cost;

      //a flag for detecting if the temp file is in the closed list is created and set to false
      boolean in_closed = false;

      //this loop will set the above boolean to true if the tile being evaluated is the same as 
      //the tile in the closed list, uses the id to find if it is
      for (int c = 0; c < closed_list.size (); c++) {

        //only calls the evaluate functions on tiles that are not on the closed list all ready
        if ( closed_list.get(c).id == temp.id) {

          //the flag is in the list and closed is  set to true
         in_closed = true;
         break;
        }
      }

      //if the tile isn't in closed its sent to a function to be evaluated
      if(!in_closed){

         //this function evaluates the tile further for adding to the open list
          evaluate_for_open(temp);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

- So far this function above simply checks to see if each surrounding node is walk-able or already on the closed list -
- if the surrounding tile passes that test its evaluated further by the following function evaluate_for_open() -

  ```
    //this function performs the final substage of the A* algorithm, it determines if the tile at args
    //should be added to the open list, if its not on there it is either not added because it is  on there
    //but at a better cost or added with its parent pointing to the better one to update the route
    void evaluate_for_open(Grid.Tile eval) {
  //default give the tile to be evaluated a pointer to the parent tile and update its movement costs, this may be changed later
  eval.parent = closed_list.get(closed_list.size()-1);

  //this line of code initialises the tile eval with the cost of the movement so far plus the cost of the distance to travel to it so far
  eval.total_score = closed_list.get(closed_list.size()-1).total_score + one_move( eval) + eval.movement_cost;  

  //the tiles F cost is evaluated
  eval.F = eval.total_score + eval.heurestic;

  //boolean records whether or not the object was found to be already in the list, is set to true just in case
  boolean not_in = true;

  //loops through the open list checking to see if the same tile exists already,
  //this way, an uninitialised open list is bypassed at the beginning and checking is reduced slightly
  //if the tile is on the list then two things can be done, if the path to this tile is cheaper
  //than a previous one the parent of that tile must be updated to point to the tile being evaluated
  for (int ol = 0; ol < open_list.size (); ol++) {

    //if the same tile has been discovered and is surrounding the current tile being evaluated
    if (open_list.get(ol).id == eval.id && one_move(eval) != -1) {

      //the tile is in the array no need to add it later
      not_in = false;

      if ( closed_list.get(closed_list.size()-1).total_score  + one_move(eval) < open_list.get(ol).total_score) {

        open_list.get(ol).parent =  closed_list.get(closed_list.size()-1);
        open_list.get(ol).total_score = closed_list.get(closed_list.size()-1).total_score + one_move(eval);
      }
    }
  }

  //check to see if the tile is the destination tile
  if (eval.id == grid_object.dest_tile.id) {

    //destination found! add that tile to the path
    found = true;
    path.add(eval);
  }

  if (not_in) {

    //adds the item on the list
    open_list.add(eval);
  }
  ```

  }

-This function checked if the tile was in the open list, if it wasnt it added it anyway-

- if it was it only added if there was a better path, it then updated its parents appropriately -
- and added it to the open list, just, it doesn't work properly-

when this function is up the code is still in the while loop, the next thing to happen is a function initialises
the closed list with the lowest F cost and removes that tile from the open_list, this will repeat until the last
tile has the same ID number as the destination tile and then break, that or the total_score of the tiles just racks
 up to a very high score or the open list remains empty;

when this happens no path has been found and an error flag is set to true and handled appropriately

or if no errors a path for player is found by going back through each tiles parent location and then the player
 moves to each one

Comment: The link to download the sketch, is not open for all to download...

Comment: Please shorten your question to contain only relevant info and fix the formatting of code blocks. Also, questions should not depend on external links.